# Overwrite a text file to update python HTML to change user password

Tags: python, html, authentication, flask, passwords

I'm trying to complete this program I need to be able to update a password saved in txt file for a user already saved in the text file and I can't figure out how to do so.

Looking for help on tasks A-C

a. Password update Form – This Python form allows a previously registered user to reset their password after they have successfully logged in.

b. Authentication functions – These Python functions will check the following NIST SP 800-63B criteria are met upon password update:

- Use the previous criteria for password length and complexity. (This work should already be
  done.)
- Compare the prospective secrets against a list that contains values known to be commonly-
  used, expected, or compromised (Provided as CommonPasswords.txt).
- If the chosen secret is found in the list, the application SHALL advise the subscriber that they
  need to select a different secret.

c. Logger – Create a log to log all failed login attempts. The Log should include date, time and IP
address.

```
from datetime import datetime
from flask import Flask, flash, redirect, render_template, request, session, url_for
import re

from wtforms import Form, PasswordField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired

app = Flask(__name__)


def validate_password(password):
SpecialSym = ['$', '@', '#', '%', '!', '&', '*']
val = True

if len(password) < 6:
    print('length should be at least 6')
    val = False

if len(password) > 20:
    print('length should be not be greater than 8')
    val = False

if not any(char.isdigit() for char in password):
    print('Password should have at least one numeral')
    val = False

if not any(char.isupper() for char in password):
    print('Password should have at least one uppercase letter')
    val = False

if not any(char.islower() for char in password):
    print('Password should have at least one lowercase letter')
    val = False

if not any(char in SpecialSym for char in password):
    print('Password should have at least one of the symbols $@#')
    val = False

if val:
    return val

else:
    return False


now = datetime.now()  # current date and time
date_time = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y, %H:%M:%S")


# each route for the pages
@app.route("/")
def welcome():
"""the welcome page"""
return render_template("welcome.html")


@app.route("/home")
def home():
"""the home page"""
if not session.get('logged_in'):
    return render_template('login.html')
else:
    return redirect('home')


@app.route("/register", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
if request.method == 'POST':
    email = request.form['email']
    password = request.form['password']
    f = open("/Users/Brian/PycharmProjects/StateList/Flask_Blog/static/database.txt", "a")
    if not validate_password(password):
        message = "Invalid Credentials"
        return render_template("register.html", error=message)
    else:
        f.write("%s %s\n" % (email, password))
        f.close()
        flash("SUCCESSFUL REGISTERED *")
        return render_template("homepage.html", error="SUCCESSFUL REGISTERED *")

else:
    return render_template("register.html")


@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
if request.method == 'POST':
    f = open("/Users/Brian/PycharmProjects/StateList/Flask_Blog/static/database.txt", "r")
    data = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    data = [x.split() for x in data]
    for item in data:
        if request.form['email'] == item[0].strip() and request.form['password'] == item[1].strip():
            session['logged_in'] = True
            return render_template('homepage.html')
        else:
            error = "Wrong Credentials"
            return render_template("login.html", error=error)
else:
    return render_template("login.html")


@app.route("/reset", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def reset():
"""reset page"""
if request.method == 'POST':
    email = request.form['email']
    password = request.form['password']
    f = open("/Users/Brian/PycharmProjects/StateList/Flask_Blog/static/database.txt", "a")
    if not validate_password(password):
        message = "Invalid Credentials"
        return render_template("reset.html", error=message)
    else:
        f.write("%s %s\n" % (email, password))
        f.close()
        flash("Password Reset *")
        return render_template("reset.html", error="Password Reset *")
```

Comment: you should read all data from file to memory, edit data in memory, and write all data back from memory to file. OR use database - ie. standard `sqlite`

Comment: on Stackoverflow you should ask only one problem on page - for other problems you should create new pages.

Comment: (C) python has standard module [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) - you should see it in many projects. It can display on screen or write to file - and you can define what values to save. And you should find many tutorials.

Comment: [flask - database](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/tutorial/database/) for SQLite. Flask has also special modules to work with other databases - ie. [flask_sqlalchemy](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iv-database) - it can be much, much better then keeping data in file. Probably it should work also with `flask-admin`, [flask-login](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-v-user-logins) or similar for login users to page.